# How do I implement a WebSocket server in javascript without Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I want to create a chat application with WebSocket, but the server is shared so I can't use Nodejs. I have searched a lot and the only thing I found were two examples, for C# and for java.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java

I need to do it on JavaScript, please help me.

I tried with someone else's server and it works, but I need to do it on my own.

This is the other server:
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/chat/ws");

Comment: So you can't do C# or Java or Node.js … what *can* you use? If Node.js isn't an option because it is a shared server then I doubt any of the other server-side JS options (such as Bun or Deno) are open to you.

Comment: If you mean everything in the Browser, then no, you can't create a websocket server in the browser.  In theory you could use WebRTC to create a chat server between multiple browsers, but without a STUN/TURN server that's not a viable option, although pricing for STUN servers are really low, or even free.  But again without a Server keeping persistent chat data would be tricky, (but not impossible.)..

Comment: I can use javascript

Comment: NodeJS is Javascript.

Comment: Yes, but I can't to install it on my server, because is shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go the WebRTC route, I manage a developer forum called [peerConnection](https://community.daily.co/) where anyone can ask questions about working with real-time communication.

So you know:

- The forum is sponsored by a WebRTC API provider, but you do not need to use their service to use the forum.
- The provider let's developers experiment with up to 10,000 free minutes.